# <Link> from react-router inside <Segment> from semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I have defined a modal for mobile view in my react app using **semantic-ui-react** library. The modal consists of a bunch of **Segment** tags that routes to the specific page using **Link** tag from react-router. The functionality is working fine as I intended, but I am facing an issue in UI. **Segment** tag takes the whole available width of the screen, but the **Link** tag only takes the space which contains the text. Now if I click the **Segment**, nothing happens,but when I click the text inside that **Segment**, it redirects to the desired page. Obviously, the issue here is that **Link** tag transpiles to **anchor** tag which only takes the space surrounding the text while **Segment** tag transpiles to **div** which takes the whole width of the screen.

I tried using {{display:inline-block}} within **Link** tag within **Segment** tag as people do with **anchor** tag within **div**, but that didn't work for me. Any suggestions?

Here is the code I currently have:

```
<Modal 
        trigger={<Button color="black" onClick={open}><Icon name="bars"/></Button>}
        open={modalOpen}
        onClose={close}
        basic
        size='small'>

        <Modal.Content>
          <Modal.Description>
            <Segment>
              <Link onClick={close} to='/login' style={{ color: '#000', display: 'inline-block' }}>{tt('navigation.login')}</Link>
            </Segment>
          </Modal.Description>
        </Modal.Content>
```

and here is the sample modal I am getting:
[example modal segment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0RgS.jpg)

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? You've described the current behaviour, but how are the elements supposed to behave?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't being clear, I want the Segment in the modal to be clickable completely, not just where the text is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the entire segment the link, you need to use the `as` prop.

```
<Segment 
  as={Link} 
  style={{display:'block'}} 
  to='your/route/here' 
/>
```

Comment: You'll need to share your markup for me to see what you currently have to be able to comment on that. The above example is basically just rendering the segment as a link instead of whatever you are currently rendering as a link. If you update your question with a JSX example, I can better answer this.

Comment: I added the code snippet along with the image in order to help you better understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: So you are saying you don't want the Segment itself to be the link, and have the onClick event for your close event handler, and instead you want to have the full width of the "row" you think the text takes to be clickable instead?

By default an anchor `<a>` tag has a `display` type of `inline`. If you change it to `inline-block` it only adds some block level attributes but it still does not take the full width of the parent container. If you add `display: block` as your style to that link, it would then make the `<a>` tag take the full width of the parent.

Comment: Note that the Segment padding will still not link or close your modal. That might confuse a user. You may still want to move your `onClick`, `as`, and `to` props up to the Segment.

Comment: No I just want the segment tag to behave like link tag but keep its original dimensions. I tried as you mentioned in your original answer and with that segment shrinked to the dimensions of link tag. I want the whole default space available by segment tag to behave like link.

Comment: Ah. I see what you are asking now. You have to put that `display:block` on the Segment component then if you don't want the inline-block display type. I'll update my answer so you can see that.

Comment: Your `display: block` suggestion worked for me. Thank you so much for your kind help. I just added it to my existing Link tag and it took the whole space available by segment tag and it is also clickable throughout the segment as well just as I wanted. I really was stuck there, thanks a lot again.

Comment: You're welcome. That is ALWAYS going to happen any time you have an element with a display type of inline or linline-block. If you want something to take the full width of it's parent container you have to use display type block. :)

Comment: Yes I guess I should pay more attention to CSS styling. Always a charm to learn from seniors , thanks buddy :)